# What type does a PHP SOAP client call return?

Tags: php, soap-client

The [PHP manual pages for the SOAP client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) don't clearly define what you can expect to be returned after making a call. The documentation for the [`soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) method says

> Usually, in WSDL mode, SOAP functions can be called as methods of the SoapClient object

But I was unable to find information about return types within the `SoapClient` documentation.

`soapCall` itelf documents a return type of a simple value or an associative array. However when I test, I get an object or type `stdClass`.

Can I rely on receiving an object of type `stdClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Soapclient::soapCall() is calling ::__call() which is a magic method [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

But basically it relays the call to an internal function call of the soap client.
So the ouput depends on what the function you called outputs.

Example on the docs:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
$client->SomeFunction($a, $b, $c);

$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c), NULL,
                    new SoapHeader(), $output_headers);
```

Comment: But the documentation for __soapCall says says it outputs a plain value (int, string etc) or an associative array, but in use, I'm getting an object returned.